# Putting tabs in ionic 2 in a component which is not a part of any tab

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I want to place tabs inside a page in which none of the tabs have that page as its component.

when i use the selector tag of the tabs inside the page it also loads the component selected by the tabs.

tab.html

```
<ion-tabs selectedIndex="0" tabsHighlight="true" > 
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Component1" tabIcon="md-person"> </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Component2" tabIcon="md-calendar"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Component3" tabIcon="md-camera"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

tabcomponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { component1,component2,component3 } from '../components';

@Component({
   selector:'custom_tabs',
   templateUrl: 'tab.html'
});

class tabs{
      tab1Root:any=component1;
      tab2Root:any=component2;
      tab3Root:any=component3;
      constructor(){

      }
}
```

Now suppose i have one more component

test.html

```
This text is not inside any tab.
<custom_tabs></custom_tabs>
```

testcomponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { tab } from '../tabcomponent';

@Component({
   templateUrl: 'test.html'
});

class test{
      constructor(){}
}
```

Here tab1Root component is visible and covering the actual content of test.html. while i am looking for a functionality in which tab1Root or any tab component only shows up if i click it.

Comment: please include the code what you have tried so far so that it would be easy to guide

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AishApp i have added the code example to describe my problem.

Comment: Tabs will set to root of the page. I believe that tabs cannot be placed as a component inside a page. You can check for Ionic segments instead of tabs too.

Comment: Thanks for your help.